# Alternatives to an RFID reader

Tags: arduino, rfid

For my Engineering project this semester, I proposed a luggage tagging system using integrated RFID. I know you're all thinking yes this has been done, but for my final presentation I'm looking for a way to present this to my professors thats not outrageously expensive. I've found readers and writers but they're low frequency, short distance and still relatively expensive. All I need is something to scan and read from a distance (not a bar code) and then show a series of numbers or letters on screen (laptop, small LCD) etc. I'm looking into an Arduino setup. Suggestions?

Comment: 1. I can't believe they actually accept Arduino in a formal Engineering project. 2. Sounds like you need something emitting an RF signal over a decent distance. This would mean changing batteries in your luggage unless you incorporate some sort of transducer to recharge internal batteries as the luggage moves. 3. If you aren't scanning a specific suitcase up close, how do you know which one you are capturing data for in a crowded airport?

Comment: This is way too vague to answer. What kind of distance are you talking about, exactly? Does the system need to be directional in some sense, or is it OK to read all luggage within the specified distance? Perhaps you should look into the [Bokode system](http://web.media.mit.edu/~ankit/bokode/bokode_sig09.pdf).

Comment: As long as the presentation can show our idea functioning regardless of the medium our professors will grade us on plausability over anything. This is only for a 2nd year project. In a passive tag active reader setup using RFID tags, only the reader has power and the tags are only active within the range of the reader. Commercially this is about 902mHz. But for presentation purposes I don't need a large distance anything from 20cm to 1m would do? I only need to show an object passing something then giving me some information in a display.

Comment: Plus the bags would go passed a reader, which would detect it, in a similar conveyor system to the current ones, then relay that information to the network effectively tracking bags. So each bags unique identifier can be recorded as it passes a specific location in the luggage handling system.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier You might be even more surprised at the [number of formal patents](https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts#hl=en&gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=ZRZ8C4GHJRDVmNVX4loomw&pq=arduino&cp=14&gs_id=1o&xhr=t&q=arduino+microcontroller&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&tbm=pts&sclient=psy-ab&oq=arduino+microc&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bmk&fp=ad9d57973130910e&biw=1280&bih=814) that have been granted, where the research was conducted using an Arduino. Yes, Arduino is fairly commonly accepted as a base platform for postgraduate engineering submissions today.

Comment: What are your options to powering the RFID tag for your project? It'll need some form of power source and a battery is simplest to implement but this may not be acceptable to your professors. So what have you found that you think you may be able to use?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I don't doubt it, I just don't want to believe it. Had I used a development board and copied other people's code in one of my electrical design projects, my professors would have flunked me. Unless, of course, the proof of concept is the real assignment and is more important than the design. With that perspective, I could understand using whatever was available.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier Often the concept is the key, the mechanism merely the tool for the job. Tools get obsolete fast, concepts usually endure. When I teach, I prefer the concept being grasped, rather than all energies getting dedicated to the mechanical aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Not **the** way to do it, but **a** way...

The RF side is the difficult (as in most variable) part. One option would be to make use of the size of the luggage and embed a "frame antenna" into it - say, 7 turns of copper wire round the entire suitcase. (Convincing manufacturers to embed this into the lining doesn't matter at this stage!)

With the suitcases upright on a conveyor belt, a similar coil beside the conveyor should pick them up at a decent range, maybe up to the size of the suitcase. (With range = size of coil, it's more like inductive coupling than RFID; are there any explicit rules against that? :-)

Spend an afternoon making up a pair of coils, choose a capacitor to resonate them BELOW the AM band (Medium Wave in Europe) - maybe just above the top of Long Wave (280kHz) or even lower like 100-150kHz. Check the regulatory aspects first!

Drive one from a signal generator and see if you can get say 1V or more from the other. If so, you can drive a Joule Thief from it, and wake up a low power CPU like the TI MSP430 to send a message.

Starting with big coils gives you an easier job of getting power across. And if you need example circuits, refer to an electronics handbook from the 1920s!

The best way to signal would be for the transmitter to detect a receiver's presence by noticing a change in load impedance when a receiver is nearby (again you can test that with just the resonant coils and a sig gen) - then the receiver's MCU can disrupt that in some way : perhaps switching in a load, or another capacitance to tune the coil off frequency.

Once the basic link works, the rest should be easy.